# Apache redirect to URI provided in query string

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

Suppose Apache 2.x receives a request for the following:

```
http://myserver1.domain.com/auth?path=http://myserver2.domain.com/somepath
```

How do I have Apache generate a redirect to the value of the `path` param? e.g. `http://myserver2.domain.com/somepath`

Comment: I am pretty sure what you need can be accomplished using [URL rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). However, I do not have enough experience to generate the rewrite rule for you.

Comment: The problem with URL rewriting is that the query string is not _matcheable_ in the Rewrite pattern part, otherwise with a `RewriteRule ^/auth\?path=(.*) $1 [R,L]` would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

This way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} path=(http.*)
RewriteRule .* %1? [R]
```

If you want to retain the query string when redirecting, remove the `?` from the third line.

See the [Apache wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString) for more examples.